# Dynamically set UIScrollView height and UITableView Height depending on content

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

**Setup**: I have a scrollview with a label, uiimage, and a tableview (grouped) nested within. The label, uiimage, and tableveiw are populated by a webservice. The last section in the grouped table view contains text that will never be the same and could be as long as 5 characters to 250+. Also, this view is pushed from a basic tableview (so it has a navigation bar. If that matters at all).

**Expected**: The tableview should extend in height depending on the length of the content received from the web service. Then set the scrollview height to accommodate the height of the tableview

**Problem**: I'm not quite sure how to approach the issue. I really only know how to change the height to fixed values, which will not work properly in many scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height of the cell are ignored; the cell cell is re-sized according to the value you return from `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or (failing that) `tableView.rowHeight`. It might *appear as if the cell is big enough* if the label in the cell is sized to be big enough, because the label is allowed to be bigger than (and render outside) the cell.

One way is to override `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return the correct height. This isn't really the intended use of UITableView (it's primarily designed for lots of rows of a single height, dynamically generated from a list of content).

Another way is to set `tableView.tableFooterView = myCustomFooter` instead. This is probably the easiest way. Size it correctly before performing the assignment (the height matters; the table view will set the width for you anyway). Also make sure that the autoresizing flags are not set, or the size will appear to randomly change when the table view changes size (e.g. on autorotation).

Comment: I'm not trying to get the height of the cell. The UITABLEVIEW which is a GROUPED TABLE needs to be made taller or shorter depending on the length of content found in the 4th section. All of the text displays within this 4th section no problem.  I can see it when I change the height of the UITABLEVIEW based on a static value. It's being cut off because it's initial height is set to 450. Then once that height is set, I need to be able to set the uiscrollview to compensate for the height of the uitableview so I can scroll down and see the entire table.

Comment: I don't understand why I would want to set something in the footer. What does 'size it correctly' mean? Like I said, I don't know what size to set it too because the text will never be the same length of characters. Thanks.

Comment: UITableView subclasses UIScrollView. Have you put a UITableView in a UIScrollView? It's much more likely to work if you just put the non-table contents into the table view header/footer. Alternatively, you can probably use tableView.contentSize (perhaps you need to force a layout? I don't know; it's icky)...

Comment: OH! I think I understand what you are saying! Place my label and uiimage in the header and let the UiTableView handle it.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Success!!! Thank you very much.  I can now focus my frustration on something else!  Haha!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just focus on the variable height element, figure out the height that fits the text there. To figure out the height that a string will take when rendered use a snippet like this:

```
CGFloat MY_TABLECELL_WIDTH = 320;
CGFloat MY_MAX_HEIGHT = 10000;
UIFont *MY_FONT = nil; // load the correct font here.
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(MY_TABLECELL_WIDTH,MY_MAX_HEIGHT);
CGSize textSize = [serverString sizeWithFont:MY_FONT 
                        constrainedToSize:maxSize 
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: The cell that contains the variable text length fits fine. The tableview isn't tall enough to display all of it nor does the scrollview accommodate the height needed to scroll.