# Get dynamic height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using `UITableView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`.
I want the cell to resize according to the content size of the tableView.

I have tried to get height of every cell by

```
 CGRect frame = [self.Table rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but it is not returning me the correct height for cells. These cells are getting dynamic height according to text.

Comment: refer :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39888662/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: My cells are getting dynamic height, i want my tableview to resize according to size of cells, as i want to disable the scroll of tableview.

Comment: @Ahmad there are lots of answers of your question is already present in stack overflow and one of the best suggested answer given by Arun , follow it.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy my issue is same as this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229297/dynamically-set-uiscrollview-and-uitableview-height-by-its-content)

Comment: @Ahmad, how many cells do you have?

Comment: @KrishnaCA number of cells depend on data returned by API

Comment: You want to vary the height of `UITableView` right? Given that at any given point, your `total height of all cells` > `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height`, I believe that it's better to fix the size of UITableView and enable it's scroll

Answer (score 0):

**In viewDidLoad method**

```
self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

//numberOfLinesOfYourLabel should be 1
```

**and then**

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   if(tableView == MainTableView){
 //Calculate height for cell for perticular indexpath of main Tableview
   }
   else if(tableView == subTableView){
  //Calculate height for cell for perticular indexpath of main Tableview  } }
```

- In cellForRow method of mainTableview reload subtableview.

Comment: My cells are getting dynamic height depending on text, setting height is not an option as im using 4 different type of cells and every cell ha 2-3 labels with different font and font size.

Comment: yes you have to calculate cell's height according to text and font in heightForRow method